# Concatenate fields in grails GORM search criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to rewrite the following hibernate query using grails criteria builder?

```
select p from Person as p 
where lower(p.firstname) + ' ' + lower(p.lastname) like '%john doe%'
```

Thanks, 
Valdemar

Comment: From a domain standpoint, have you considered just combining the fields into one (e.g. `Person.fullName`)? If the name is going to be treated as a single string throughout your entire application, it probably doesn't make sense to split it up. Plus, the whole first name/last name design can get whacky when you introduce different cultures and eccentricities. Is "Bono" or "Sting" a first name or last name? :)

Comment: Yes i've considered that, but unfortunately it's not an option in this case. And the question is interesting anyways I think :)

Comment: ¿Did you find the way to cancatenate fields in criteria?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Would something like this be OK?

```
or {
   ilike('firstname', '%fred%')
   ilike('lastname', '%fred%')
}
```

Comment: No, I want, for example, to be able to search for "john doe" across both firstname and lastname.

Comment: Then all I can think of is using the sqlRestriction clause.

Comment: I could also think about 4 conditions inside 'or' :)

Comment: If end customers are allowed to enter the search text freely, the most robust way could be to separate the input on whitespaces and create numberOfInputs*2 `ilike` criteria clauses (also, in some cultures, people sometimes input their last name first and you'd catch that as well).

Comment: Thanks gregor, that's a good idea. I'll choose this answer even though the solution is in the comments!

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but your answer doesn’t solve the asked question. Your solution is OK for majority of cases, but is not what needed in this case. Someone found a solution for concatenating?